# Whats the correct terminology to describe action of scanning RFID card?

Tags: user-interface, terminology, rfid

Sorry for an untraditional question that has more to do with terminology than with coding, but I believe that here at StackOverflow are lots of people whose native language is english, and they could make the right suggestions. So the deal is that I'm writing FrontEnd UI for self-service kiosk. First thing that an user must do to use kiosk is scan his RFID contactless card by bringing it to a reader.

Problem is simple but confusing at the same time - what's the best and most understandable expression to describe an action of quickly weaving card in front of reader that's located on a vertical kiosk surface right under screen and marked with LED circle?

My guesses and comments I've came up till now:

- **Place your card on the circle**

*I guess that you can't use the expression "place on" if we talk about vertical surface and the fact that scanning only takes a tenth of a second, right? Some older folks can misunderstand and keep their cards pressed for minutes at time while making selections on screen.*

- **Scan your card**

*Again - older folks maybe will not understand what "scan" means. In best case scenarios they may have used swipe-cards in past.*

- **Scan your card by pressing against the circle**

*Very long phrasing for such a simple action?*

- **Weave your card in front of circle**

*Sounds a bit stupid, I guess..*

- **Bring your card to circle**

*This seems most understandable so far*

Please, maybe some native speaker could give me his opinion on the subject, so I can at least have my consciousness clean that I've at least tried my best to come up with best solution. :)

Comment: One thing you may not have considered is what they should do or see after doing the action they carry out. Then at least if they misunderstand the instruction, but fully understand the intention, they will better succeed through experimentation at least. For example: "Hold your card on the circle until it goes green" assuming you can change the LED colour from your kiosk app.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I intend to make "check mark" animation inside card-shaped outline on the screen as well as blink the LED circle as soon as card is read and validated, so I believe that only thing, I must choose between, is initial invitation for scanning action - so that users instantly grasp the concept of scanning card by weaving in front of reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means definitive, but what about **Place card near circle** - this is based on common verbiage that came to mind from [Exxon's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedpass) [Speedpass](http://www.groceryshopforfree.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/Speedpass.jpg). And since you will have a confirmation indicator (i.e. check mark animation) in addition to the text it seems enough to communicate the action required.

I agree you should make it as intuitive as possible, but it is difficult to fully educate a person who has never used an RFID card through a kiosk with universal text.